# Bash for Android automation - Can't compare variable resulting from read\awk

Tags: android, bash, shell, awk, adb

I'm using ADB to get the density of an Android device's screen, then want to map that to mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc. I'm able to save the density into a variable using read and awk, however I'm unable to do any sort of comparison on it. As a Bash newb I'm not sure what variable type results, and have tried to find out, for instance, if it's less than 300 in anyway I can, with no positive results so far.

```
function device(){
   adb -s <device ID> shell getprop ro.sf.lcd_density | while read line  
   do 
      PPI=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
      echo "$PPI"  
   done
}

device
PPI=$(device)
echo $PPI

#this is where the problem starts, I can not find any way to do a comparison of $PPI. 
if (("$PPI" = "560"));
then
    echo "rock star"
fi
```

Comment: please edit in some example output. What are you currently getting for `$PPI`? Also, I recommend using `echo XXX"$PPI"XXX` to be sure there are no extra space chars in the output. Good luck.

Comment: `adb -s <device ID> shell getprop ro.sf.lcd_density | tr -d '\r' | while read line`

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses, eks: `PPI=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}'` This can also be written: `PPI=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$line")`. Also always double quote variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement to get the density. This worked for me:

```
ppi=$(adb wait-for-device shell getprop ro.sf.lcd_density | tr -d '\r')
density="N/A"
case $ppi in
    120)
        density="ldpi" ;;
    160)
        density="mdpi" ;;
    240)
        density="hdpi" ;;
    480)
        density="xhdpi" ;;
    320)
        density="xxhdpi" ;;
    640)
        density="xxxhdpi" ;;
esac

echo $density
```

Updated code using `-le` (less than or equal to):

```
get_ppi() {
    adb wait-for-device shell getprop ro.sf.lcd_density | tr -d '\r'
}

get_density() {
    _ppi=$1
    if [ $_ppi -le 120 ]; then
        echo "ldpi"
    elif [ $_ppi -le 160 ]; then
        echo "mdpi"
    elif [ $_ppi -le 240 ]; then
        echo "hdpi"
    elif [ $_ppi -le 480 ]; then
        echo "xhdpi"
    elif [ $_ppi -le 320 ]; then
        echo "xxhdpi"
    elif [ $_ppi -le 640 ]; then
        echo "xxxhdpi"
    else
        echo "N/A"
    fi
}

ppi=$(get_ppi)
density=$(get_density $ppi)

echo $ppi
echo $density
```

Output on my device:

```
480
xhdpi
```

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses, eks: `ppi=$(get_ppi)`

Comment: @toddlikesbeer your welcome. If it answered you question then you can accept it. If not, let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code did not work is that `adb` uses `\r\n` for the line separator even in OSX and Linux. So your `$PPI` value was not `560` but `560\r`. You need to strip those extra `\r` before you do any comparisons:

```
ADBShell () { adb ${2+-s} $2 shell "$1" | tr -d '\r'
}

DPI () { ADBShell "getprop ro.sf.lcd_density" $1
}

Density () {
    local DPI=$(DPI $1)
    case 1 in
        $(($DPI <= 120))) echo "ldpi" ;;
        $(($DPI <= 160))) echo "mdpi" ;;
        $(($DPI <= 240))) echo "hdpi" ;;
        $(($DPI <= 320))) echo "xhdpi" ;;
        $(($DPI <= 480))) echo "xxhdpi" ;;
        $(($DPI <= 640))) echo "xxxhdpi" ;;
    esac
}


echo "$(Density $DEVICE_ID) ($(DPI $DEVICE_ID)dpi)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, that was definitely it. Time to get to know the tr command.